# PHP-Soap already installed still Class 'SoapClient' not found error

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Installed soap version:

Output of following command :

> yum search php-soap

php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol

Also,

> yum search php | grep -i soap

Returns

> php-pear-SOAP.noarch : Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) Client/Server for
>
> php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP
>   protocol
>
> php56u-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP
>   protocol
>
> php-ZendFramework-Soap.noarch : SOAP web services server part helper
>
> php-ZendFramework2-Soap.noarch : Zend Framework 2: SOAP Component

Under module authors, It shows SOAP Brad Lafountain, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov. But my phpinfo() call does not show the SOAP section.

PHP Version 5.6.5

Comment: Can you provide more details on what server image you're using? Can you also explain where the error is appearing, and what you are doing to cause this error?

Comment: $client = new SoapClient('http://[some link here]');
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in ...

Comment: Did you install the module? You will need to run `yum install php-soap`. To see whether it's been installed, run `php -m | grep soap`. If nothing is output, the module has not been installed.

Comment: I have edited question with output of 'yum search php | grep -i soap' command.

Comment: What happens when you run `yum install php-soap` in your terminal and try your code again?

Comment: I got the following error : 
Error: php56u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: Also, my phpinfo() call does not show the SOAP section.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: OK, try running this instead: `yum install php56u-soap` (or whatever the PHP 5.6 SOAP module is called).

Comment: It works. Thanks for the all the comments. Great :)

Comment: Can you please answer the question and mark the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum install php56u-soap
```

worked for me.